# Android studio can't see Nexus 5x whatever I try

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I know this has been asked before and answered in a variety of ways, most of which I have now tried.
I have Windows 7 and a recently purchased Nexus 5X.

Enabled USB debugging? YES.

I connect the two using a USB-A to USB-C brand new cable.
The PC can see the Nexus in Windows Explorer but not its files.
I then down-swipe the Nexus and change the default "Use USB for" from Charging to MTP File transfers.
Windows Explorer can now see the Nexus "Internal Storage" folder with all its files.
In Android Studio I then click the "Run" icon. It displays the "Choose Device" window but no device is shown.
I down-swipe the Nexus again and change the "Use USB for" from MTP File Transfer to Photos PTP transfer.
Then try running the program - No change. Nothing. Change back to MTP - nothing.

I have successfully transferred screenshots and images from the Nexus to the PC.

I have been trying to solve this for an accumulated time of about 12 hours and am now at my wits end.

Can anyone help to stop me going completely and utterly mad?

Thank you!

Comment: try this link.http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: That did it, Exception Lover!  Well done that man!

Comment: John of York Accept my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google USB Driver is required for Windows only in order to perform adb debugging with any of the  [Google Nexus devices.Click here for more information](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)